# trying to make 3 divs centered inside a div

Tags: html, css, center

Hi I'm trying to center 3 divs inside of a div.

```css
.outer {
    border: 1px solid blue;
    width: 80%;
}

.inner {
    border: 1px solid red;
    float: left;
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    margin-left: 20px;
}

.clear {
    clear: both;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer">
    <div class="inner"></div>
    <div class="inner"></div>
    <div class="inner"></div>
    <div class="clear"></div>
</div>
```

Can someone help on this.

Thanks.

Comment: post your code, not a link to your code

Comment: Post the code in the code tag and the link after that please. And please more details, maybe a picture of what you want would be better.

Comment: try [flex](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)

Comment: @paulalexandru the solution you posted works excellent except it doesn't work on ie8 since first-of-type isn't supported in ie8. is there a solution without using polyfills for ie8? thanks

Comment: Yes, if you dont want to use first of type, just add margin-left 0 as an inline style on that div and it will work the same.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to achieve [this](http://jsfiddle.net/paulalexandru/mdhuwc1L/) just:

HTML:

```
<div class="outer">
    <div style="display: inline-block;">
        <div class="inner"></div>
        <div class="inner"></div>
        <div class="inner"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.outer{
    border: 1px solid blue;
    width: 80%;
    text-align: center;
}

.inner:first-of-type{
    margin-left: 0px;
}

.inner{
    border: 1px solid red;
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    margin-left: 20px;
    float: left;
}
```